# JSON массив в HTTP POST запросе

Tags: php

Начал вникать в запросы к серверу в php, но немного недопонимаю примеры. Например, тело HTTP POST запроса содержит массив. Поясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в данной строке:

```
$curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/example.php' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"array": [1,2,3,4,5]}'
```

И как в phpstorm организовать подобный ввод, чтобы считать массив из данной строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Поясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в данной строке:
>   `$curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/example.php' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"array": [1,2,3,4,5]}'`

Отправка запроса POST на IP в вашем случае localhost

- `protocol://domain:port/path/to/file`
- -X - request тип запроса (GET, POST, PUT  etc.)
- -H - headers "внутренная" инфа для сервера

> И как в phpstorm организовать подобный ввод, чтобы считать массив из данной строки?

Использовать `json_decode` на стороне сервера, файл **example.php**:

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode($_POST);
```

или так

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($data);
```

или так

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){ // Проверка того что ввод POST 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($data); 
}
```

Так как полыслается формат JSON.

---

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) - преобразует строку типа JSON в переменную PHP (объект дефолт или массив если установить true вторым параметром)
- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) - читает файл в строку
- [php://input](http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php) - доступ к потокам ввода-вывода.

---

P.S.: phpStrom это среда разработки.

Comment: Хм...вроде стало понятно, спасибо. А каким образом теперь формировать ответ, не подскажите? В какую сторону глядеть, чтобы в тело HTTP запроса вернуть ответ?

Comment: @IWProgrammer не за что. Это уже другой вопрос, задайте отдельно. К новому вопросу, добавьте код с вашими попытками, опишите, что работает, а что нет. Какого результата, хотели бы добиться.

Comment: уже сделано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857982/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-json-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be-http-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0