# Возвращение json-объекта в тело HTTP ответа

Tags: php

Как вернуть скриптом php ответ в тело HTTP запроса? Есть некий запрос:

```
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/findMin.php' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"elements":
[40,8,511,14,22]}'
```

Далее идет php скрипт, который ищет минимальный элемент в "elements". Вопрос, как вернуть json-объект в тело HTTP ответа? Ниже приведён скрипт:

```
<?php
$elements = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
return min($elements["elements"]);
```

Comment: Если PHP код выполняется вне функции, то зачем **return**? Нужно что-то вывести в ответ - сделай **echo / print**.

Comment: @Vitaly , return - потому что я не знаю, как в HTTP ответ запихать ответ ). Написал, чтобы показать, что хочу вернуть в HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос, как вернуть json-объект в тело HTTP ответа?

Вот так возращают `JSON`:

```
<?php
$elements = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
|// Возращает {"min": 2} это можно обработать на стороне клиента в JS
echo json_encode(['min' => min($elements["elements"]) ]);
```

---

- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) - возвращает строку типа JSON.

Comment: B , т.е. http-ответ, это просто вывод на консоль? Разве ответ не должен быть примерно в такой же форме, как и запрос? С cURL и пр.?

Comment: @IWProgrammer вы это возвращает на страницу, которая сделала изначальный запрос. `Клиент -> Сервер -> Клиент`. Вашем случае Клиента представлял curl, того же эффекта можно добится и с запросом из браузера.

Comment: и не требуется ответ собирать в HTTP-тело?

Comment: B, точнее не так. не требуется разве, как вы написали, отправить ответ клиенту в форме, какой он задал вопрос. Т.е. $ curl......

Comment: @IWProgrammer curl это для обращения на сервер (условно говоря), для ответа клиенту этого не требуется (т.к. соединение уже создано).

Comment: B, благодарю, теперь разобрался